# App-level Build.Gradle file -> error Cannot resolve Symbol "GradleException" flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, dart

OS :- Windows 10 home 64bit
IDE:- Android Studio version 3.5
Flutter version :- 1.9. 1 +hotflix .6
Gradle version :- 6.0.1

An error which I am facing.
[Android's App Level Build.Gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D2xW.png)
in App level build.gradle file. I am getting an error ~ cannot resolve symbol "GradleException" [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aA5U.png).
I have checked the google but I am unable to solve my problem. I had tried almost everything like 1 Invalidate Chaches/restart [Invalidate Chaches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYDH3.png)
Changes some setting in File --> Project Structure settings [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZkd0.png) , [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym0Kq.png)
 , [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wWH0.png) But nothing worked for me.....

one more thing I have noticed that I am facing similar in error in almost every project either it's new or old. whenever I open Android's app-level Build.gradle file. its automatically showing the error that " cannot resolve symbol GradleException"

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29608#issuecomment-548649907

Comment: Thank you so much brother.  The portion which is worker for is that change the name from "GradleException" to "FileNotFoundException"